# How to get a list of columns in django_tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

Is it possible to get a list of the columns in a django_tables2 table

```
# tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables    

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    firstcol = tables.Column()
    secondcol = tables.Column()
```

then use a function ...

```
 >>> MyTable.function_to_list_cols()
 ['firstcol', 'secondcol']
```

Comment: Apologies I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. The function is MyTable.base_columns.keys()

Comment: you're spot on, that's the right approach.